# Animate, fade one UILabel after the other

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

I want to animate some text so that it fades in and as the first word fades out the second fades in and then the same for the third.

I can see how to fade text in but not different ones after each other.

How should I do that?

Comment: There is a pod called CLTypingLabel, I thought it worked great on numberOfLines = 1.

Comment: Nobody knows which platform you are working on.

Comment: I’m working on iOS.

Comment: Thank you, that was all that was needed, like El Tomato did. A guidance that the question was ambiguous is good enough for me to correct and learn. I don't need to have a comment that implies  am stupid and don't have a clue. From now I will make sure my questions are better for you guys. I do appreciate your time on them and don't want to waste time if its not right. And yes it can be and is intimidating for a new person to come and ask questions from all the veterans, to then slated for "not having a clue" Agin thank you for your time to guide me on my questioning. It will be better.